# How change the format of a data before writing to the database from a parser?

Tags: java

I am writing data in the database through a parser from a txt file. 
The code I use is this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/RPR/Desktop/test.txt"));

            String dados[] = new String[6];
            String linha = reader.readLine();

            while (linha != null) {

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(linha, ";\"");

                dados[0] = st.nextToken();
                dados[1] = st.nextToken(); 
                dados[2] = st.nextToken();
                dados[3] = st.nextToken();
                dados[4] = st.nextToken();

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yy");

PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) conexao.prepareStatement("replace into registos"
   + " (date, hour, IdSensor, Temp, Humid) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
                        try {
                            stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateFormat.parse(dados[0]).getTime()));
                            stmt.setString(2, dados[1]);
                            stmt.setString(3, dados[2]);
                            stmt.setString(4, dados[3]);


                        } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
                            Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                        }

stmt.executeUpdate();

                linha = reader.readLine();
```

However there are data that come in this format: `---` I would like to turn them into `0` before writing to the database. Does anyone know any to do this?

Comment: Use regex to check if data matches template and then choose what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clean up your data, use the `replace()` method:

```
stmt.setString(2, dados[1].replace("-", "0")); // etc for other data
```

Comment: Very Thanks, you save my life Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

After you've parsed the date with SimpleDataFormat, it's in binary format already and that binary format will be passed to Database by setDate and executeUpdate, so I don't think that you need to do anything.

The way how date will look like when you get it from your Database is a different question and will depend on how you format the date **after you get it from the Database**.